# Which is more efficient update where or if exists then update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I would like to know which is more efficient and why.

```
if not exists (select 1 from table where ID = 101 and TT = 5)
begin
    update table 
    set TT = 5
    where ID = 101;
end;
```

or

```
update table 
set TT = 5
where ID = 101 and TT <> 5;
```

Assume there is a clustered index on ID (nothing more table used default table creation setting)

Comment: Seems like something you can quite easily test yourself

Comment: Depends if you have triggers, as the second version will cause the trigger to run.

Comment: Normally an actual update would not be issued, but if you use `SNAPSHOT` then an actual update will also be issued. Also `rowversion` will get updated in the second version, as will `GENERATED AS` columns.

Comment: @Charlieface there are no triggers but I don't understand how the top one won't execute a trigger. I assume that only if a row gets updated a trigger will fire??? Does the bottom one execute a trigger if no row gets updated???

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214777/trigger-firing-despite-no-rows-being-affected wow this is new to me. I see that if now rows are updated then a trigger can fire

Comment: Exactly, so in the first version the trigger doesn't fire at all. In the second, the trigger fires with 0 rows. If you modify version 2 and remove ` and TT <> 5` then the trigger fires with all rows, even if none are modified

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will generally [optimize a non-updating `UPDATE`](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/the-impact-of-non-updating-updates.html) to not actually issue any updates. Therefore, with a simple table, you are not going to see much difference.

- If you have triggers, they will be fired if the `UPDATE` statement executes, irrelevant of how many rows are updated.

  - If the `UPDATE` statement executes over rows, even if they are modified to the same value, they will appear in the trigger.
  - If rows are filtered out with a `WHERE` clause, for example `and TT <> 5`, then the trigger will fire with 0 rows
- `rowversion` and `GENERATED AS` columns will be updated regardless.
- Clustered key columns will cause a delete and insert of the whole row.
- If `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` or `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` are on, *even if not being used*, then due to the way row-versioning works, an actual update will always be made.
- If the `IF EXISTS` is complex, it still may not be worth doing, but in simple cases it usually is.

Answer (score 1):

WHERE, IF EXISTS and IN all have different performance benefits. I would suggest checking out these two articles.

https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/

https://sqlchitchat.com/sqldev/tsql/semi-joins-in-sql-server/